# PHP retrieving elements from file

Tags: php, for-loop

I am retrieving information from a text document and trying to test if the users input matches any of the information in the text document.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
$userpassfile = fopen("usernamepass.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$username = $_POST["usernamepassword"];
$_SESSION['$usernamepassword'] = $_POST["usernamepassword"];
while(!feof($userpassfile)){
    $line = fgets($userpassfile);
    $users = explode("#", $line);
    for($x=0; $x<sizeof($users); $x++){
        if($users[$x]==$username){
            header('Location: booking.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }
    }   
}
if($username=="ADMINadmin"){
    header('LOCATION: admin.php');
}

fclose($usernamefile);
```

When it checks the information in the txt, it seems to only check the first and last element. I don't know why. I thought it was because in the for loop there was a < not <=, however when set to <= it wont check the file at all. Any ideas, cheers!

Comment: This could be an issue with line encodings being different on MS-Windows and all other systems. That can break what php treats as a "line" inside the file.

Comment: As a suggestion, don't make an user/password login with a text file. There will be dangerous several security problems .

Comment: Its just a project. Nothing that is going to get developed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
$userpassfile = fopen("usernamepass.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$username = $_POST["usernamepassword"];
$_SESSION['$usernamepassword'] = $_POST["usernamepassword"];

if($username=="ADMINadmin"){
    header('LOCATION: admin.php');
    fclose($usernamefile);
    exit; // If user is admin, there is no need for further checking.
} else {
    header('Location: login.php'); // Set redirect to login.php by default
}

while(!feof($userpassfile)){
    $line = fgets($userpassfile);
    $users = explode("#", $line);
    if(in_array($username, users) {
       // If user was found, override redirect to login.php
       // and set it to booking.php
       header('Location: booking.php');
       // And there is no need to iterate further, so stop the loop
       break;
    }
}

fclose($usernamefile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code must look like this

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<?php
$username = $_POST["usernamepassword"];
$_SESSION['$usernamepassword'] = $_POST["usernamepassword"];
if($username=="ADMINadmin"){
    header('LOCATION: admin.php');
} else {
    $userpassfile = fopen("usernamepass.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $in_file = false;
    while(!feof($userpassfile)){
        if($in_file) {
            break;
        }
        $users = explode("#", fgets($userpassfile));
        $in_file = in_array($username, $users);
    }

    if($in_file) {
        header('Location: booking.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
    fclose($userpassfile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // note here that i has removed your DOCTYPE INPUT ...

    $location                       = NULL;
    $defaultPage                    = "login.php";
    $username                       = $_POST["usernamepassword"];
    $_SESSION['$usernamepassword']  = $username;

    // this test must be the first ... for performance
    if($username=="ADMINadmin"){
        $location = "admin.php";
    }
    else {
        $userpassfile = fopen("usernamepass.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        while(!feof($userpassfile)){
            $line   = fgets($userpassfile);
            $users  = explode("#", $line);
            for($x=0; $x<sizeof($users); $x++){
                // i have added trim : maybe there is spaces or other invisible chars in your file
                // note: if your login system is case insensitive so use this condition :
                //       if(strtolower(trim($users[$x])) == strtolower($username)){ ... }
                if (trim($users[$x]) == $username){
                    $location = "booking.php";
                    break;
                } 
                // here it is the mistake : if the first token of the first line is not the connected user
                // so php will redirect to login page
                /*
                else {
                    header('Location: login.php');
                }
                */
            }   
        }
        fclose($usernamefile);
    }
    // it is a good practice to be explicit... for maintenance simplicity
    if (is_null($location)) {
        $location = $defaultPage;
    }

    header("Location: " . $location);
?>
```